# "where's that to?"

Tags: etymology, prepositions

In Plymouth, and other areas of Devon, it is common to suffix the question "where's that?" with *to*.

e.g.

> Steve: I'm off to see Rita.
>
> Dave: Oh yeah? Where's Rita to?

or

> Steve: I'm off to Roborough
>
> Dave: Where's that to?

Is there an origins story for this construction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OED, s.v. "to", meaning A.4.a, says

> a. Expressing simple position: At, in (a place, also fig. a condition, etc.). Cf. German zu Berlin, zu hause. Now only dial. and U.S. colloq. Cf. home n.1 and adj. Phrases 1e.

It gives examples from 925 to 1977, including this from 1899:

> In Somerset‥it is correct to say ‘I bought this to Taunton’.

Comment: I didn't realise it was such an old idiom. Thanks!