# "go home straight" or "go straight home"

Tags: word-usage

Which one of the following is the proper usage below?

"go home straight"

or

"go straight home"?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Straight* is a specialized adverb that can pre-modify prepositions.

- straight in
- straight past
- straight up
- straight out
- straight home

It can't pre-modify adverbs:

- *straight beautifully

*Home* is usually a preposition in English (- although there is a noun *home* too). In the Original Poster's example we need:

- Go straight home.

*Straight* always *pre*-modifies prepositions. It must therefore occur before *home*.

[Now We *could* say:

- Go home straight.

But here straight would be an adjective, it would be describing the subject of the verb *you*. It has the same structure as:

- Go home tired.
- Go home happy.
- Go home straight.

The adjective *straight* has several meanings, but one of them is *sober* or not drunk. So go home straight might be understood as:

- Go home sober!]

Comment: On the other hand, "go home straight away" is common and perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @szarka That's because *away* is also a preposition! (but a temporal one, not a locative one). So there's two prepositions there *home* and *away*. The second one, namely *away*, is pre-modified by *straight* :)

Answer (score 2):

Go home or straight home, is the correct usage of the phrase & home in "go home" is an adverb of place.

Examples:

Listen my son! Don't loiter after class, and **go straight home.**

Do you **go home straight** when you get off work early?

*We do not use a preposition (a word such as 'at' or 'to') before home when it is an adverb:*

I travel home by bus (NOT- I travel to/at home by bus).

He returned home (NOT- He returned to home).

References:

[Home is not a noun in "Go home"](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/home_2)

[Definition of home NOAD](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54336/playing-upstairs-vs-playing-home)

[See also- close to home](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/close_2#p008-001085421) 
  
a) if a remark or criticism is close to home, it makes you feel uncomfortable because it is likely to be true:

His comments struck unpleasantly close to home.

Comment: Home is a preposition not an adverb! That's why you can use *straight* with it!

Comment: I somewhat agree..when "home" is acting as an adv.implying direction, we don't need a preposition.

Comment: Although lots of people do still cal it an adverb  .... :(

Answer (score -1):

I suppose either could be correct depending on the context, but the more common usage would be

'go straight home'

which would generally mean to go home without deviating or delaying while en-route.