# "leave to" or "leave for"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, differences, prepositions, to-for

Which of the following is correct?

> I am leaving for London.
>
> I am leaving to London.

I have always thought the first one is correct till I came across [the name of this painting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Leaving_to_Egypt_%28Perugino%29).

Comment: related: [“where's that to?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/wheres-that-to)

Comment: By the way, since the painter is Italian, the title of the painting is not the original title by the artist but a translation from somebody who may not have translated it correctly.

Comment: Agreed. I today certainly wouldn’t translate *Il Viaggio di Mosè in Egitto* with anything involving “leaving to”.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both are correct, but the first is more common modern parlance.  *Leaving to* is likely an ellipsis of *leaving to go to*.

Comment: I don't think it's missing *go to* at all. As the answer to the question I link to suggests, *to* by itself is accepted and has been for hundreds of years.

Comment: @MattЭллен That question also says "Now only dial. and U.S. colloq." I've never heard it in England (but then I don't often go to Somerset and the West Country), and I'd never use "leave to London".

Comment: @AndrewLeach I bet it's heard (well maybe not the London part) in Somerset, Devon and Cornwall

Comment: How about "I'm about to leave to the station?"

Comment: I'm happy that it should be a West Country or American dialect. The US inherited many dialectal forms, or has developed them separately [UK: *got*; US still has *gotten*]. But I'd never leave to anywhere, it's always *leave for*.

Comment: @MattЭллен - If it's a US usage I think it's regional.  I've lived many places in the US and never heard anyone "leave to (somewhere)."

Answer (score 4):

"Leave to" is not an American usage - as an American ESL teacher/ editor, I can guarantee that it is not in our grammar books. The accepted standard preposition that completes the infinitive in this case is "for" - in recent times, I've heard an Irish woman using "to" and did a Google search to see if it was perhaps a BE form that I wasn't familiar with.